# Going to Bali with arachnophobia

Tags: indonesia, vacations, bali

I'm planning to go to Bali for a week or two in mid-September, and I'm suffering from severe arachnophobia. I live in France and even if spiders are quite little here, I'm having a bad time trying to avoid them.

I'm currently not sure where I'll stay (north or south), and I don't have a real budget limit (I can stay at good hotels).

Do you have specific tips or information that will help me avoid them there, or should I just avoid Bali all-together?

Comment: Travelling with arachnophobia could get you stopped by customs. Hehe. Kidding aside, bali seems to have a crazy amount of spiders, so you might want to avoid it considering your "severe" case of arachnophobia. But you can call the hotel in advance and ask them if spiders are common to the area.

Answer (score 4):

You will be hard pressed to avoid spiders in their entirety in Bali or anywhere in SE Asia.  Spiders ranging from tiny to fairly large live throughout the region, but that doesn't mean they will be jumping out at you around every corner.

How you can minimize potential encounters depends in large part on what you want to do while in Bali.  If you plan to hang out at the beaches, shop a little, stay at a nice resort, then you should be basically OK.  If you want to visit the historic temples, caves, hike to waterfalls, etc, then there is a good chance of coming across spiders / webs.

Answer (score 0):

From my experience, there is mostly 2 type of (large) spider
The first (some black hairy spider) lives in the molden wooden houses)
The second (yellow and black with long legs) lives outdoor in rural area

If you stay in a tourist hotel of Denpasar, you're unlikely to meet any.
In a slum or a cosy countryside hotel, it's different

none of those are giant stuff. About twice the size of the big French garden spider.

I tend to like the black hairy spider because they eat those fat ugly cockroaches. If you are also scared of cockroaches, stay in France

(Bonjour depuis Paris, d'ailleurs)